# How to get user information from database when the only thing in client browser is the AuthToken?

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework

Building my first app with a real backend.

In my app, when a user registers or logs in (with username and password), a token is saved to the cookies of their browser. After registration (or when logging in), I can easily return information pertaining to this particular user (name, id, etc.).

```
# Django REST backend for loggin in and getting user token
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email,
            'user_type': user.user_type,
        })
```

Next time the user accesses the app in the same device, the token will be there and I can make the http requests for which a token is necessary. However, since I won't be logging the user in again (not asking for username and password every single session), I won't get that user's additional information.

In my React app I would like to **have the user set in state at all times**, e.g. `user = {first_name: 'john', user_type: 'p'}` but **I don't know how to get the user info when the only thing I have is their token.**

I am more than welcome to criticism to this approach and to learning what's the best way of doing this. I don't even know if keeping the user in state is the right way to do things...

I tried this:

```
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        print(self.request.user)
        return self.request.user


curl -H "Authorization: Token b2e33463esdf8as7d9f8j34lf98sd8a" http://localhost:8000/current-user/
```

but the return value from self.request.user is AnonymousUser

Answer (score 0):

If it's not sensitive information, such as username, id, user type, first name, etc. you can store this in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: weclome to SO! that won't work for my use case. Imagine I need to fetch data from other endpoints and specify the user_id in those requests. simply by changing user_id in localStorage, data pertaining to other users could be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

problem was in my settings.py file:

```
  'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
      'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of answer to this question. first part is criticism to your approach and little bit of guidance towards better approach, second part of the answer is about your actual question.

Lets start with second part first.
From the look of your code, you are already storing the `key` in `Token` Table along with `User`. You can easily get the user by first running this query `token = Token.objects.get(key=key).select_related('user')` and then simple `user = token.user` will give you token.

Coming to first part now.
Since you are using DRF, you do not need to override the class unless extremely necessary. If you want user with each approved request, what you can do is simply add your Token verification class to Settings of DRF

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I found how to do that this code will help you

```
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = Account.objects.filter(username=request.user)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response('You have to login first')
```